# Investment sheets has an error while converting usd to eur

Tags: google-sheets

I get an error with my code: =IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("$",B3),RIGHT(B3,LEN(B3)-1)*A1000,B3))
The error is: Incorrect number of arguments for IF. Expected between 2 and 3 arguments, but found 1 arguments.

It should convert b3 to euros if there is a "$" before the number.A1000= usd/eur in numbers.

The sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1RnYi9H70fqS5wy1OQO2jex7xdNl-1kFLVbm3uDjejTg/edit?usp=sharing .I am trying in G/H 29

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Comment: I posted the link!

Comment: You are required to post a [mcve] here, **within your question**, and [not a link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254430/162698) to any other site.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("$"; B3)); RIGHT(B3; LEN(B3)-1)*A1000; B3)
```

[image]

Comment: Then i get the error: formula parse error

Comment: @Bram answer updated. try now

Comment: Thank you! Now i am tryin to put it in the total worth colum bit i get the same error. the code i now have is: =IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("$", B3)); G3*A1000; G3)

Comment: @Bram you cant use commas `,`in your sheet. use semicolon `;`